# valgrind --trace-children=yes reports leak despite atexit cleanup

Tags: c, memory-leaks, static, valgrind, atexit

I'm trying to avoid false positives with valgrind, but I'm suck with a combination of `atexit()` and `fork()`, despite using `--trace-children=yes`.  My code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

static int * arr;

static void cleanup() {
    free(arr);
    printf("free arr as: %p\n", (void *)arr);
}

int main()
{
    arr = malloc(16 * sizeof(int));
    printf("allocated arr as: %p\n", (void *)arr);
    atexit(cleanup);

    pid_t pid = fork();
    if (pid == -1) {
        exit(1);
    } else if (pid == 0) {
        // child
        _exit(0);
    } else {
        // parent
        exit(0);
    }
}
```

Command-line:

```
$ clang -Weverything leak.c 
$ valgrind --trace-children=yes ./a.out 
==3287== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==3287== Copyright (C) 2002-2015, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==3287== Using Valgrind-3.12.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==3287== Command: ./a.out
==3287== 
allocated arr as: 0x5202040
free arr as: 0x5202040
==3288== 
==3288== HEAP SUMMARY:
==3288==     in use at exit: 64 bytes in 1 blocks
==3288==   total heap usage: 2 allocs, 1 frees, 1,088 bytes allocated
==3288== 
==3288== LEAK SUMMARY:
==3288==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==3288==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==3288==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==3288==    still reachable: 64 bytes in 1 blocks
==3288==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==3288== Rerun with --leak-check=full to see details of leaked memory
==3288== 
==3288== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==3288== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
==3287== 
==3287== HEAP SUMMARY:
==3287==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==3287==   total heap usage: 2 allocs, 2 frees, 1,088 bytes allocated
==3287== 
==3287== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==3287== 
==3287== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==3287== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Based on the `printf()` output, it looks like there's no leaks.  Can I convince valgrind of this, or should I just add this to my valgrind suppression file?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Based on the printf() output, it looks like there's no leaks. Can I convince valgrind of this, or should I just add this to my valgrind suppression file?

It appears that valgrind is right.  If you interpret the `printf()` output as indicating that there are no leaks, then you're not appreciating the effect of `fork()`.

When you fork a child, it gets a complete copy of its parent's address space.  This is typically implemented via copy-on-write pages, but it still constitutes memory belonging to the child.  In your case, that includes a copy of dynamically-allocated array `arr`.

The child exits by calling `_exit()`, so although it inherits its parent's exit-handler registrations, registered exit handlers are not called in that process.  You can tell that is so because you see the output of `cleanup()` only once.  As a result, the copy of `arr` belonging to the child is never freed, as valgrind tells you.

It's a bit pedantic to call this a memory leak, though.  The memory in question is still reachable when the program terminates, at which time it gets reclaimed by the system.  It simply is not *explicitly* freed before termination.

Comment: Thank you!  Yes, I did indeed misunderstand the "copy of its parents' address space" part of `fork()`.  To help anybody who stumbles across this question in the future, please google "virtual address space" and/or read: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5365635/7541781

Answer (score 4):

You are using _exit() in child process. As per _exit's man page :

```
The function _exit() is like exit(3), but does not call any functions registered with atexit(3) or on_exit(3).
```

Change it to exit(0). It should work.

Comment: Thanks!  I've seen other documentation about `fork()` saying that the child should call `_exit()` rather than `exit()`[1].  However, manually calling `cleanup()` within the `// child` seems to work.
  
[1] "For technical reasons, the POSIX _exit function must be used here instead of the C standard exit function.)"
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork_(system_call)#Application_usage

Comment: @gperciva you should understand the *reasons* behind recommendations such as you describe.  The primary one in that particular case is to avoid calling registered exit handlers, which is often desirable in a forked child process.  In the event that you actually *want* to call registered exit handlers, as it seems you do in this case, you probably just want to use `exit()` instead of `_Exit()`, as this answer suggests.

Comment: @gperciva, note also that although `_exit()` is not part of the C standard library, the standard library has `_Exit()` since C99, which does the same thing and is a bit more portable.

Comment: @gperciva, please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2329640/how-to-exit-a-child-process-exit-vs-exit for exit() versus _exit() usage.